# Pretrained NN Finetuning with Keras. How to freeze Batch Normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**So I didnt write my code in tf.keras** and according to this tutorial for finetuning with a pretrained NN: [https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#freezing-layers-understanding-the-trainable-attribute](https:///keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#freezing-layers-understanding-the-trainable-attribute),

I have to set the parameter **`training=False`** when calling the pretrained model, so that when I later unfreeze for finetuning, **Batch Normalization doesnt destroy my model**. But how do I do that in keras (Remember: I didnt write it in tf.keras). Is it even necessary in keras to do that?

**The code:**

```
def baseline_model():
    pretrained_model = Xception(include_top=False, weights="imagenet")

    for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    general_input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))

    x = pretrained_model(general_input,training=False)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
...
```

**Gives me the error, when calling `model = baseline_model()`:**

```
TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'training'
```

How do I do that best? I tried rewriting everything in tf.keras, but theres errors popping up everyhwere when I tried to do it...

**EDIT: My keras version is 2.3.1 and tensorflow 2.2.0**.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED my previous answer after doing some additional research:
I did some reading and it seems like there is some trickery in how BatchNorm layer behaves when frozen. This is a good thread talking about it: github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7085 seems like `training=false` parameter is necessary to correctly freeze BatchNorm layer and it was added in Keras 2.1.3, so my advice for you is to make sure your Keras/TF version is higher

Comment: So you say it seems that fine tuning works? i.e. Batch Normalization layers in the pretrained model arent updated/ dont wreck the model when I unfreeze+retrain them?

Comment: Correct. Ones you do this: `layer.trainable = False` it freezes all the weights in said layer and it's not trainable any more. You can check it later by running `model.summary()` - it should display number of trainable and non-trainable parameters for the whole model

Comment: Yes but when finetuning I would set layer.trainable = True for some/all layers?

Comment: Yes you would. Regarding BatchNorm I did some reading and it seems like there is some trickery in how BatchNorm layer behaves when frozen. This is a good thread talking about it: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7085 seems like `training=false` parameter was added in Keras 2.1.3 so make sure your Keras/TF version is up-to-date

Comment: My keras version is 2.3.1 and tensorflow 2.2.0 so the above code would have to work. Or  do I have to set it to False some different way?